# Excel VBA - PivotItems returns inexesting value

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, visible

In an Excel Workbook, I have "static" pivot table on a sheet, that is based on data from another sheet.

I'm refreshing the data on my data sheet (thank you captain Obvious !), then I want to show ALL the items, exept the blank one, so I'm running throw all the PivotItems to set them to visible, and, at the end, unselecting the blank one :

```
i = 1

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TCD").PivotTables(i).PivotFields("CODETAT").ClearAllFilters
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TCD").PivotTables(i).PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
For Each PvI In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TCD").PivotTables(i).PivotFields("CODETAT").PivotItems
    PvI.Visible = True
Next

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TCD").PivotTables(i).PivotFields("CODETAT").PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
```

At the last occurs of my loop, on the 4th PivotItems, I have an error of execution '1004' (I'll translate it from french, it may me some errors, sorry) "Impossible to define the property Visible of the class PivoItem", so I checked a few things :

```
?ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TCD").PivotTables(i).PivotFields("CODETAT").PivotItems.count
 4
```

for x = 1 to 4 :

```
?ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TCD").PivotTables(i).PivotFields("CODETAT").PivotItems(x)
(blank)
SFT
ACQ
TEP
```

It look like I have 4 items in my Pivot Table, but

[image]

And also, when I check my datas, I only have 2 different stats :
[image]

So where does this 4th PivotItems' element is coming from, and how can I get ride of it ?
Thank you.

Comment: I had a surprising issue like that, check in the `Pivot Table options` (right click on the table), in `Data` tab, you should find `Retain items deleted from the data source`, choose `None` for `Number of items to retain per field`. Then refresh all should be in order! ;)  (that error drove me mad for hours!^^)

Comment: Actually it was already to None, I unchecked everything, selected max, saved, closed, checked again, and set to None, and now its working properly... Thx for the tip, I've never heard about this !
http://i.stack.imgur.com/oFSOT.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a surprising issue like that, you need to check in the Pivot Table options :

- Right click on the pivot table,
- Select `Pivot Table options`
- Go in `Data` tab
- Find `Retain items deleted from the data source`
- **Choose `None`** for `Number of items to retain per field`!
- Then refresh! All should be OK now! ;)

(that thing drove me mad for hours!^^)

[image]